# How do I export a Pages document on my iPad to PDF and save it in Files?

Tags: ipad, pdf, pages

On the Apple Pages iPad app, you can export a document to PDF. When it creates the PDF, it gives you the option to “Share” it. There are many apps you can share it to, including Gmail, Notes, and Books, but you cannot just share it directly to Files. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I save a file as a PDF a panel opens as shown below. there you can save it to files. What version of iPadOS are you running?

[image]